# Find All Subclasses of a given class (Android)

Tags: java, android, reflection

I've used [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) Library to Find All Subclasses of a given class in Java before.

This is a code snippet that I use in a **simple java** project :

```
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(PACKAGE_NAME);

    Set<Class<? extends SuperClass>> subTypes =
            reflections.getSubTypesOf(SuperClass.class);

    for (Class<? extends SuperClass> subType : subTypes) {

        log("Subclass = " + subType.getSimpleName());
    }
```

When I run the same code in **android** project , "subType" List returns empty.

Can Anybody help me to get this work on Android ?

**EDIT**
Jars I add for the whole thing to work are :

- reflections-0.9.9-RC1-uberjar.jar
- javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
- guava-14.0.1.jar

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679254/all-super-classes-of-a-class)?

Comment: @t0mm13b. That's about super classes, not subclasses.

Comment: @RohitJain then why is the OP's code referring to `SuperClass.Class`?

Comment: @t0mm13b. Perhaps, he wants all the subclasses of the `SuperClass` in the wildcard bound.

Comment: @RohitJain Maybe... yeah that could be what the OP's intention was,

Comment: I need all SUB types , not SUPER type...

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try this:

```
public abstract class ClassScanner {

    private static final String TAG = "ClassScanner"; 
    private Context mContext;

    public ClassScanner(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    void scan() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException {
        long timeBegin = System.currentTimeMillis();

        PathClassLoader classLoader = (PathClassLoader) getContext().getClassLoader();
        //PathClassLoader classLoader = (PathClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();//This also works good
        DexFile dexFile = new DexFile(getContext().getPackageCodePath());
        Enumeration<String> classNames = dexFile.entries();
        while (classNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String className = classNames.nextElement();
            if (isTargetClassName(className)) {
                //Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(className);//java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                //Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(className, false, classLoader);//tested on 魅蓝Note(M463C)_Android4.4.4 and Mi2s_Android5.1.1
                Class<?> aClass = classLoader.loadClass(className);//tested on 魅蓝Note(M463C)_Android4.4.4 and Mi2s_Android5.1.1
                if (isTargetClass(aClass)) {
                    onScanResult(aClass);
                }
            }
        }

        long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeElapsed = timeEnd - timeBegin;
        Log.d(TAG, "scan() cost " + timeElapsed + "ms");
    }

    protected abstract boolean isTargetClassName(String className);

    protected abstract boolean isTargetClass(Class clazz);

    protected abstract void onScanResult(Class clazz);
}
```

and this is a example how to use:

```
    new ClassScanner(context) {

    @Override
    protected boolean isTargetClassName(String className) {
        return className.startsWith(getContext().getPackageName())//I want classes under my package
                && !className.contains("$");//I don't need none-static inner classes
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isTargetClass(Class clazz) {
        return AbsFactory.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)//I want subclasses of AbsFactory
                && !Modifier.isAbstract(clazz.getModifiers());//I don't want abstract classes
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScanResult(Class clazz) {
        Constructor constructor = null;
        try {
            constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            constructor.newInstance();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}.scan();
```

Comment: this is working pretty cool, I think it should be accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

This might not work due to the compilation process used in Android. The source code is converted into .class files with the Java compiler. The next step turns the .class files into Android .dex files (Dalvik bytecode) and they are unlikely to keep all meta-data.

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html

Comment: Yes I thought so... Do you think there is a way to get it work anyhow ? Maybe to write some hook that will work at compile time ?

Comment: Sorry, no compiler guru. You might check something like this out http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

Comment: Interesting post.Thank you.I will look forward to find a solution.

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/127

Answer (score 0):

There is an official API for dealing with dex files. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexFile.html) for details. Basically, given path of the .dex file, you can enumerate all the files inside it. To get the URL of the `classes.dex`, you can use

```
  Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("classes.dex")
```

(you may need to cut the trailing `"!/classes.dex"`, can't check it right now). Then, you can iterate over the classes.dex contents and attempt to load all the classes you find this way. (`Class.forName`), and, finally, check whatever class properties you need. Keep in mind, however, that `classes.dex` contains **all** the classes, and "all" can be "quite a lot". There are also other performance issues to remember when dealing with .dex files. You should, however, be fine, as long as you don't attempt something needlessly inefficient. Especially since Reflections accomplishes its magic in a similar manner, as far as I remamber.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my one-method-solution based on fantouch's answer.

Result will also contain inderect descendants.

```
public class Utils
{
    // ...

    public static ArrayList<Class> GetSubClasses( Context context, String packageName, Class targetSuperClass )
    {
        ArrayList<Class> subClasses = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {
            DexFile dex = new DexFile( context.getPackageCodePath() );
            for ( Enumeration<String> iterator = dex.entries(); iterator.hasMoreElements(); )
            {
                String className = iterator.nextElement();

                if ( !className.startsWith( packageName ) || className.contains("$") )
                {
                    continue;
                }

                Class classObj = Class.forName( className );

                Class superClass = classObj;
                while ( true )
                {
                    superClass = superClass.getSuperclass();

                    if ( superClass == null || superClass == Object.class )
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    if ( superClass == targetSuperClass )
                    {
                        subClasses.add( classObj );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return subClasses;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Kotlin solution that also works with interfaces. What you need is a real `Context` instance, so be aware that you are not able to use this approach in unit-tests.
Note that `DexFile` is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/dalvik/system/DexFile) due to API fragility with no useful replacement.

```
private inline fun <reified T> getAllSubclasses(
    startsWithPackage: String,
    context: Context,
): Set<Class<out T>> {
    val classNames = DexFile(context.packageCodePath).entries()
    val classLoader = context.classLoader

    val superclass = T::class.java

    val result = mutableSetOf<Class<out T>>()

    classNames.iterator().forEach { className ->
        if (className.startsWith(startsWithPackage) && className.contains("$").not()) {
            val loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass(className)
            if (loadedClass.superclass == superclass || loadedClass.interfaces.contains(superclass)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                result.add(loadedClass as Class<out T>)
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

The method above could be used like that.

```
val subclasses = getAllSubclasses<SuperClass>("com.example", context)
```